# best way to remove strings in array with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

lets say i've got this array:

```
array = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6", "str7", "str8"]
```

what i'm doing:

```
array.delete_if {|i| i == "str1" || i == "str3" || i == "str5"}
```

i got:

```
["str2", "str4", "str6", "str7", "str8"]
```

are there any better approach in ruby to do this ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could do this:

```
array - %w{str1 str2 str3}
```

Note that this returns a new array with `"str1"`, `"str2"`, and `"str3"` removed, rather than modifiying `array` directly (as `delete_if` does). You can reassign the new array to `array` concisely like this:

```
array -= %w{str1 str2 str3}
```

Comment: `array -= %w[ ... ]` would do an in-place reassignment but would not alter any references to the original array.

Comment: Good idea; I added it to the original answer.

Comment: just so people know, %w{word word2} does not accept variables containing strings. I didn't know and it will not remove the string from the array. I used ```array -= [variable_containing_string]``` to make it work

Answer (score 2):

```
array.reject{|e| e=~ /str[135]/}
```